# ACF not saving data and only showing spinner from front side wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, save, advanced-custom-fields

I have shown the ACF form on front side and now trying to save the data but its spinning the loading and not saving posts.I am trying below code.what i am doing wrong

```
<?php

add_action( 'get_header', 'tsm_do_acf_form_head', 1 );
function tsm_do_acf_form_head() {
    // Bail if not logged in or not able to post
    if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can('publish_posts') ) ) {
        return;
    }
    acf_form_head();
}
add_shortcode( 'intake_form', 'intake_form_open' );
function intake_form_open($atts) {

// Bail if not logged in or able to post
    if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in()|| current_user_can('publish_posts') ) ) {
        echo '<p>You must be a registered author to post.</p>';
        return;
    }
?> 
    <div id="personal-information">

        <?php

        $edit_post = array(
            'post_id'            => 'new', // Create a new post
        // PUT IN YOUR OWN FIELD GROUP ID(s)
            'field_groups'       => array($atts['id']), // Create post field group ID(s)
            'form'               => true,
            'return'             => '%post_url%', // Redirect to new post url
            'html_before_fields' => '',
            'html_after_fields'  => '',
            'submit_value'       => 'Submit Post',
            'updated_message'    => 'Saved!'
        );
        acf_form( $edit_post );
        ?>

    </div>
<?php

}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'tsm_do_pre_save_post', 10, 2 );
function tsm_do_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // Bail if not logged in or not able to post
    if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can('publish_posts') ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_type'     => 'post', // Your post type ( post, page, custom post type )
        'post_status'   => 'private', // (publish, draft, private, etc.)
        'post_title'    => 'Comments ACF Form', // Post Title ACF field key
        'post_content'  => $_POST['acf']['field_56badad4fb425'], // Post Content ACF field key
    );
    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    // Save the fields to the post
    do_action( 'acf/save_post' , $post_id );
    return $post_id;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ACF or some other plugin is throwing an error on the backend. Turn Debug on, in wordpress, and check the error log for the issue.

Do check to ensure that you do not have any other front end page posting plugin that is enabled. I had the same issue when WP Front end plugin was also enabled.

Once I disabled it, everything worked.